# Where was the Batman during the "terrorist" event?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

In **Suicide Squad**, during the main plot attack of Midway City by the demon Enchantress and her brother, where was the Batman or the Flash? Why didn't they help Task Force X (aka **The Suicide Squad**)?

**In the stinger** - They show Bruce Wayne (aka **Batman**) is talking to Amanda waller for meta humans files. Guess he was in town?

Comment: They were in Gotham and Central City, respectively. I don't think there is a good in-universe explanation why a few hundred superheroes from that universe didn't swarm Midway City.

Comment: I think Batman would be knowing of the attack and also knew that there are no super heroes in Midway city.

Comment: I can understand Batman not being there (he's just a guy, after all, and we don't know how far Midway City is from Gotham), but the Flash really has no excuse. At the end of the day, it's a film about the Suicide Squad, which is why Flash didn't run in and save the day.

Comment: @dizzle, midway city is nebraska, Gotham is east coast maybe Connecticut or Delaware. As for Flash, the stinger shows the government and batsy kept the event under media blackout. Barry was oblivious.

Comment: @verdan because this universe doesn't have a few hundred heroes yet. All recently emerging.

Comment: From the post-credit sequence of SS and the end of BvS you can see that Batman is currently travelling around the world trying to convince heroes to form the Justice League with him. It's entirely plausible at this point Batman could be out finding Aquaman which we have seen footage of. As for the rest of the heroes, they're all just starting to come about. They're not established just yet. Flash seems to be the only one besides Bats in SS and he could have his own issues in Central City.

Comment: @BigTallJosh But he didn't got the file about superheros till the end of film , so obviously he didn't started travelling yet.

Comment: @AnkitSharma During BvS he decrypted Lex Luther's files on the meta-humans. So he already had some information on them. At the end of BvS he speaks with WW about bringing them all together. We can assume there is a fair period of time between end BvS and start SS. There is nothing to strictly dictate *when* he speaks to Waller at the end of SS, although him saying something like "let my team do it instead" we can probs assume it is post-SS. Even then that could just be additional information. The files Waller gave show Enchantress too, he could be after more info on metas. We wont know till JL

Comment: From what we know of Aquaman, he's not doing the hero thing yet. He's just a known meta/super.

Comment: Considering that one of Chicago's airports is called "[Midway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midway_International_Airport)", it seems reasonable to guess that Midway City = Chicago... also, as Batman V Superman shows, Gotham is, essentially, across the river from Metropolis, which implies that Gotham and Metropolis are each boroughs of NYC... probably Manhattan and Queens or Brooklyn.

Comment: @catija there's also midway California. But the on screen maps were closer to nebraska than Chicago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Out of universe explanation :**

The film is about the Suicide squad and Batman or the Flash barging in to save the day wouldn't make much sense as 'Dr R Dizzle' pointed out.

**In universe explanation :**

This mission was about **proving the worth of Waller's Suicide squad** to the elites. Batman saving the day would have just been an embarrassment for her and she might have asked Wayne to stand down until they were sure of the squad's failure if he wanted the files.

That would mean more casualties in case of failure but that wouldn't be out of character for Amanda.

We don't know about the Flash but we can safely assume Amanda Waller has leverage on him (as well as everyone else :

> Because getting people to act against their own self-interest for the national security of the United States is what [she does] for a living